# Citing chapters, sections, equations, and figures from other book chapters (notebooks)

Tags: automaticnumbering, figurecaption, equationnumbered

I am writing a book in the *Mathematica* book format and currently have separate notebooks for each chapter, e.g., **BookCh1.nb**, **BookCh2.nb**, etc.

I'd like to use `AutomaticNumbering` *between* chapters, so for instance in the Chapter 2 notebook I'd like to write:

```
As we saw in Figure 1.9 and Equation 1.6, the Fourier transform...
```

where the numbering comes from Tags in the *other* chapter.

How do I do that?

Comment: Just curious, but are you using [Wolfram Book Tools](https://www.wolfram-media.com/resources/)?

Comment: @Chris K:  Yes, I often use the Book Tools (but I didn't see a solution to my problem there).